# Row height and background color the same as sheet's one leads to default style in ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I was following [this](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Row-Height-and-Styles) example and noticed that when a row has height changed and background color the same as for its sheet then background color disappears from the row (or it changes to the Default one).
It seems to be that style is completely lost for such rows:

[image]

**Code to reproduce problem:**

###### Different colors for sheet (Green) and row (Red) - CORRECT

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var document = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = document.Worksheets.Add("Row Settings");
    ws.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Green;

    var row1 = ws.Row(2);
    row1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
    row1.Height = 30;

    var row2 = ws.Row(4);
    row2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkOrange;
    row2.Height = 3;

    document.SaveAs("Correct-Diff.xlsx");
}
```

[image]

###### The same colors for sheet (Red) and row (Red) WITHOUT height adjustment - CORRECT

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var document = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = document.Worksheets.Add("Row Settings");
    ws.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;

    var row1 = ws.Row(2);
    row1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;

    var row2 = ws.Row(4);
    row2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkOrange;
    row2.Height = 3;

    document.SaveAs("Correct-NoHeight.xlsx");
}
```

[image]

###### The same colors for sheet (Red) and row (Red) WITH height adjustment - INCORRECT

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var document = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = document.Worksheets.Add("Row Settings");
    ws.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;

    var row1 = ws.Row(2);
    row1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
    row1.Height = 30;

    var row2 = ws.Row(4);
    row2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkOrange;
    row2.Height = 3;

    document.SaveAs("Incorrect.xlsx");
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to resize a row while keeping its color the same as sheet one, basically achieving the correct for of 3rd example?

P.S. It's a copy of [the issue I opened](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1813) just in case if somebody else experienced and fixed the issue

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the described issue with 0.95.4.0 via NuGet. Which .Net are you you running there?

Comment: @DerSchnitz It was netstadard2.0 and netcoreapp2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was expected it's a bug that should be closed by the [fix](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/1815)